# Loop through each table row and swap two cells

Tags: jquery, loops, foreach

this question may have been answered in different ways, but not in one solution that I can find.

I have a table with a few rows and cells.  I need to swap the position of cell2 with cell3 and not change any content.  It works, up to the point of swapping the cells. I'm just missing something.

Thank you in advance!

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr> 
    <td>1 APPLES</td>
    <td>3 ORANGES</td>
    <td>2 BANANAS</td>
    <td>4 GRAPES</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1 APPLES</td>
    <td>3 ORANGES</td>
    <td>2 BANANAS</td>
    <td>4 GRAPES</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1 APPLES</td>
    <td>3 ORANGES</td>
    <td>2 BANANAS</td>
    <td>4 GRAPES</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's my jquery -- trying to make use of the .each()

```
$('table tbody tr').each(function () {    
    //make sure I found the rows
    $(this).css('border', '2px solid yellowgreen');
    
    //find the 2nd cell
    $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').each(function () {
    
        //make it blue so I know the correct cell is found
        $(this).css('background', 'orange');

        //find the 2nd child in the current row
        $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').each(function () {
            
            //change color to check correct cell    
            $(this).css('background','tan');    
            
            //move the 2nd cell after the 3rd cell -- swap places.
            $(this).insertAfter('td:nth-child(2)');
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to select all the `td` in the 3rd row and loop through them moving them before their previous sibling, something like this:

```js
$('table tbody tr td:nth-child(3)').each(function() {
  let $td = $(this);
  $td.insertBefore($td.prev());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>1 APPLES</td>
    <td>3 ORANGES</td>
    <td>2 BANANAS</td>
    <td>4 GRAPES</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1 APPLES</td>
    <td>3 ORANGES</td>
    <td>2 BANANAS</td>
    <td>4 GRAPES</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1 APPLES</td>
    <td>3 ORANGES</td>
    <td>2 BANANAS</td>
    <td>4 GRAPES</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

There's other combinations you can use, selecting the second `td` in the row and using `insertAfter()`, or `next()` etc, but the general pattern outlined above would be the same.

Note however that the best solution to this problem would be to fix the output that creates this HTML in the first place.

Comment: Thanks!! Worked perfectly!! I guess I was trying too hard and over-engineered it! For some reason I felt I needed to find the row, then the 2nd child and move that next to the 3rd child.  Instead of finding the path to the TD, then swapping the position

Comment: No problem, glad to help